# changing URL in joomla

Tags: sql-server, database, url, joomla2.5

I have looked through the answers and I am not sure which will work for me , so I am writing the question again, Hoping for a response that might work.
Here : http://norstore-trd-bio0.hpc.ntnu.no/tfcp/
I have a database on server and I am using Joomla to create the website and manage database.
This was a test version, now I want to have the database here it self but use the new URL for website http://tfcheckpoint.org/ bought by godaddy.com.

According to godaddy i tried to first mask the website that is kinda a redirect tfcheckpoint.org to orginal site as explained here:
http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/422/forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name
BUT, this cause some links to be broken and not accessible anymore, since the external URL is fixed.

Secondly I looked for other solutions and tried to get the mysql dump and replace the old url with new url everywhere and imported the sql file again, but nothing changed. probably because the new site is masked and I have to unmask it. Or should I install Joomla again and start from scratch with the new URL.

But is there a proper way to do this. I don't think moving the database to new hosting server is the solution as many people have their data on local servers while they use these fancy domain names. 
Please guide me if there is a standard procedure to do so.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell from your question, you are merely trying to move a Joomla site from one hoster's server to another? You may even be moving between hosters...my answer still stands.

Firstly I have heard of many issues with GoDaddy for Joomla sites.  But that is probably an answer for a different question.

In terms of moving your test site and "turning" it into a live site on a new server, this can be done with a 3rd party tool like Akeeba Backup.

For Joomla's settings in the new location,  you will need to change the details to accommodate the new hoster's details for database and file locations. This is done through the Site Restoration process(made very easy in Akeeba). There is also a setting for LiveSite that you have have set which would need to be changed manually in /newlocation ofyour files/joomla install/configuration.php.

In terms of DNS settings, your new domain should point to the new hoster's server and a 301 redirect against the old domain pointing to the new one should cover all the bases.

I hope that answers your question.  If not, I suggest rewriting the question to be more clear.  You will probably get more answers